# Java data structure for reverse insert

Tags: java, android, arrays, data-structures, reverse

Is there a datastructure in Java which supports reverse insert? I want to add values to a datastructure. I do not know how many in advance. The values should be inserted in the following row:

```
datastructure.insert(1); //datastructure is: {1}                 
datastructure.insert(4); //datastructure is: {4,1}       
datastructure.insert(9); //datastructure is: {9,4,1}
```

The last inserted value should always be the first. Which data structure suits best?

Comment: Try Deque that allows insert at last, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#addLast%28E%29

Comment: you have 2 use genric collection stack<E> and with methods push and pop of FIFO concepts

Comment: +1 Not sure why so many think Stack is the right answer.  Shows it's worth asking the question because Stack is not a good idea. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach is to use a [Deque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)  You shouldn't use a Stack unless you have a really old version of Java.  A Stack btw will be the opposite order you need.

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(4);
stack.push(9);
System.out.println("stack: " + stack);
Deque<Integer> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.addFirst(1);
deque.addFirst(4);
deque.addFirst(9);
System.out.println("deque: " + deque);
```

prints

```
stack: [1, 4, 9]
deque: [9, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Thats it what I actually where looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This is called a stack. See `Stack<E>`, methods are `push()` and `pop()`

Comment: a stack will produce `[1, 4, 9]` see my answer.  It is a legacy class anyway.

Comment: True on both counts. Plus, I wasn't certain iteration order mattered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *java.util.ArrayDeque* instead of *Stack*. From [Oracle Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to *Stack* class. For example:

```
Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
stack.push(1);
stack.push(2);
stack.push(3);
stack.push(4);
```

You will get values like this { 4, 3, 2, 1}.

The class *java.util.ArrayDeque* provides all the operations (for ex push() and pop() ) of a LIFO data structure

Answer (score 0):

We are on StackOverflow, and you probably want to use a Stack ;) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) and add new Elements using `addFirst()` or a [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simplest thing you can do is implementing a Stack,push all your elements one by one and then pop them out .It follows Last In first Out which is exactly what you want.